# Can I use a for loop to create objects in java?

Tags: java, loops, swing, jframe, jbutton

Can I initialize multiple objects in a single loop?

Here's what a snippet of my code looks like. As you can see, it becomes hard to look at from a glance and takes up too much space.

I'd like to be able to create the buttons in one for loop and then modify in another for loop.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    MyFrame() {

        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        JButton button3 = new JButton();
        JButton button4 = new JButton();
        JButton button5 = new JButton();
        JButton button6 = new JButton();
        JButton button7 = new JButton();
        JButton button8 = new JButton();
        JButton button9 = new JButton();
        JButton button0 = new JButton();


        button1.setBounds(60, 60, 50, 50);
        button2.setBounds(120,60,50,50);
        button3.setBounds(180,60,50,50);
        button4.setBounds(60,120,50,50);
        button5.setBounds(120,120,50,50);
        button6.setBounds(180,120,50,50);
        button7.setBounds(60,180,50,50);
        button8.setBounds(120,180,50,50);
        button9.setBounds(180,180,50,50);
        button0.setBounds(120,240,50,50);

    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an ArrayList and running the loop to define a new button on each iteration with the desired values should work

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a for loop to create the buttons.

Here's a GUI I created.

[image: Ten Button GUI]

It's not a good idea to use absolute positioning (`setBounds`) when creating a GUI.  You should use the [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

I used a `GridLayout` to position the buttons.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TenButtonGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TenButtonGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ten Button GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            if (i == 9) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");
                panel.add(label);
            } else {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                panel.add(button);
            }
        }

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```java
List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
int[][] bounds = {{60, 60, 50, 50}, {120,60,50,50}}; //add more bound quadruplets

// iterating over the values in the bounds array
Arrays.asList(bounds).forEach(v -> {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setBounds(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]);
    buttons.add(button);
});
```

In the end you will find your buttons in the `buttons` List.